# Magento order ID reorder

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.4, fulfillment

With set of products in my shopping cart When I login and start an order I get assigned an orderID.

If I then sit on my order, or logout and come back again, my cart products is still there and the order ID I was given (potentailly days ago) is still there. In the mean time the there are 100's of orders placed after me. And now am placing my oder means my oder id is before 100 old ID's. These all are good and goes well.

But In the backend, our fulfilment people will have batched well beyond the current ID and my old order ID will get lost in a void(because if i am ordering after one year or so my ID could be 1000 id's Back).

SO, is it possible and easy and safe to force Magento to re-issue a new ORDER ID upon step one of the checkout?  If not, can we prevent Magento from remembering your cart state after you logout) or perhaps each time you re-login, whichever is easier?

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to `System>Config>Checkout>Shopping Cart` and change the value for `Quote Lifetime (days)`, you will be able to reduce the length of time that the cart is stays alive.

Alternatively, I would recommend that you change the fulfilment order selection criteria to work on the order date, not order ID.

Comment: The latter is the real fix here. Order ID is a handy string, but it is for human consumption. Use the date if you want to catch everything.

Comment: but when we chnage the "Quote Lifetime" then my cart products will be lost for the customers? Let me try it out. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes, they will be lost.  That's why I (and Joseph) suggest that you change the fulfillment order selection criteria instead.